# AllocConsole() with hidden console window

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-console

I'm trying to launch bash.exe, running in interactive mode, as a child process. The only way I have found to do this is to launch bash.exe from a console program, or to AllocConsole() to a non-console program and then launch it. It seems that if it isn't launched from a console program, or at least a program which has been allocated a console, bash.exe refuses to launch in interactive mode.

Since the base program has to be a GUI program, I have to use AllocConsole. However, if I do so, this creates a visible console. That won't be acceptable for the program I'm building.

I know how to create hidden child processes, but the console popping up comes from AllocConsole, not CreateProcess. There are a number of questions like this, but most of them end with workarounds, and it seems like my situation precludes all the workarounds I can find.

How can I use AllocConsole without a console appearing? Failing that, how can I launch bash.exe as a child process of a GUI program, in interactive mode, without using AllocConsole?

Comment: Have you tried launching bash with [`CreateProcess()` using redirected STD(IN|OUT|ERR) handles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)?  You don't actually need a console window in order to interact with a console app from a GUI app.  Otherwise, try using `GetConsoleWindow()` after `AllocConsole()` and then hide the window or move it offscreen

Comment: Do a bit of juggling. Use `CreateProcess` to spawn a console process such as cmd.exe with a hidden window via `STARTUPINFO` or without a window (i.e. `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`), attach to it via `AttachConsole`, and then terminate the initial console process.

Comment: Yep! Bash.exe does not like those pipes and will refuse to run in interactive mode. I have only ever gotten it to run in interactive mode as a child process by passing it the console handles from a console run by the parent process.

Hiding or moving it offscreen will not fix the problem. The flicker will be a significant problem for a fullscreen GUI app. I need it to never have a console appear at all.

Comment: Run it from a service? Btw are you referring to WSL bash or some other like cygwin or mingw?

Comment: Don't run it as a service

Comment: WSL bash. I'm gonna work with eryksun's suggestion for now, I'll confirm whether I can get it running.

Comment: For **fullscreen GUI app** you may try to set **WS_EX_TOPMOST** or **SetWindowPos** with **HWND_TOPMOST**. This will keep app window above console.

Answer (score 0):

eryksun's approach worked. I launch the process with the following settings. I can then use AttachConsole and FreeConsole with the processId to manipulate the console.

```
siStartInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
siStartInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

    BOOL success = CreateProcess(
        applicationAddress, // absolute path to the application
        TEXT("-i"),         // command line 
        NULL,               // process security attributes 
        NULL,               // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,               // handles are inherited 
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,               // creation flags 
        NULL,               // use parent's environment 
        NULL,               // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,       // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);       // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION
```